# ASP.NET WebAPI HttpGet Action - model is null after querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model, deserialization

The querystring below is not being deserialized by the MVC action. The action gets hit ok, but I'm getting  null value for `searchModel` in the action.

https://test.api.domain.com:9090/mont/contact/searchemployee?lastname=Smith

**EDIT**: Simplified Model

**Model**

```
public class EmployeeSearchModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Action:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Employee> SearchEmployee(EmployeeSearchModel searchModel)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        try
        {
            if (searchModel != null)
            {
                //some logic
            }
            else
            {
                //dirty feedback for testing - this is what the action returns
                employees.Add(new Employee { FirstName = "searchModel was null" });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { WriteFileLog(_logPath, e.ToString()); }

        return employees;
    }
```

Comment: try using string instead of Employee object.

Comment: @NMK  thanks, already tried, it works. but need to use model

Comment: I think you should put `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]`

Comment: Only simple type will be binded as part of the url otherwise you need to use Body not the URL for complex types.

Comment: @the_ruby_racer thanks, yes, `[HttpPost]` works. But would like to use `[HttpGet]`

Comment: NMK is correct. You cannot pass complex types through a regular GET request.

Comment: please see my edit. i have created the simplest model with no subclassing or complex lists. still getting null model in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that ASP.NET MVC or Web API? From the fact that you return a list of employees from the controller action instead of `ActionResult` I can see that it's Web API. If so, you could apply `[FromUri]` attribute to the model:

```
public List<Employee> SearchEmployee([FromUri]EmployeeSearchModel searchModel)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much takemyoxygen! It is WebAPI.

Comment: hehe, I thought he was using MVC4 not WebAPI based off the question :)